# Default Value for Dropdown

Tags: google-app-maker

Can't seem to find an answer to this issue easily.

Default values for fields you want to display and allow editing, the best place seems to be to set the `widget.value` in a draft record, so default date `widget.value = new Date()`, etc.

How do I reference a dropdown where the dropdown is a related table lookup, e.g., a list of Properties where the bindings are `@datasources.Property.Items` for the options and `@datasource.Item.Property` for the value.

If I do `console.log(widget.value);` I get `object Object`, which is what I would expect because it is of type object. But how can I set (and retrieve) its value?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Which value are you hoping to retrieve? Key or some other column from the Property datasource? It is the same as any other object reference actually, so to get the Property key it would be `widget.value._key` or for any other column `widget.value.YourColumnName`. Unfortunately in this regards code autocompletion does not work.

Comment: That's no good I'm afraid. _key "identifies a record within a model. The key for records created in create mode or manual save mode is a temporary key used by the App Maker client and does not represent the actual key that the record will have once it is saved." So it's a temp string value.

Comment: I'm interested in setting a default value of a dropdown in the onAttach event in a form. Code complete does show the values, e.g., widget.value.Status is the field i'm trying to write to. But when you put widget.value.Status = "Open"; in the onAttach event it throws the error:

Cannot set property 'Status' of null at Add_Incident.Form1.Form1Body.fieldStatus.onAttach:1:21

if you try and retrieve the value
console.log(widget.value.Status);
it also throws an error:

Cannot read property 'Status' of null at Edit_Incident.Form1.Form1Body.status.onAttach:1:26

Comment: So I'm still not sure how to work this. There must be some object notation for this, i.e. widget.value = datasource.Status.Items[x]

Comment: I think you need to consider when your widget actually has data to grab a value from. It is not in the onAttach event since the options/value have not loaded given that it is tied to a different datasource. I would try to log the widget.value.Status in the onDataLoad event instead maybe and then take it from there.

Comment: The question title says default values. So the onAttach is appropriate for setting a value and this is the question. How do I write widget.value = object to set a default value. What is the object syntax that defines the data element.

Comment: You're missing an important point here. I'm not saying that the onAttach event is not appropriate for setting a default value generally speaking. However, it is in this context. Your widget options are based on a different datasource than your form datasource, therefore when your widget attaches your options array is in fact empty, unless you previously loaded the datasource that your options are based on. Otherwise, when the widget first attaches it will call the load action on the datasource that the options are based on. Anyway I have a possible solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this for a similar situation in my own application. Do note that there is a minimal delay before the value in the dropdown actually populates. I'm not sure what your alternative solution could be due to the reason stated in my last comment above. I might suggest setting this in your form model onBeforeCreate event instead, but then you would loose the ability to change the relation in the form itself so that might not work for you.

Dropdown widget onAttach event:

```
var datasource = app.datasources.Property;
if(!datasource.loaded) {
  datasource.load(function() {
    var index = datasource.items.map(function(i){return i.Status;}).indexOf('Open');
    if(index !== -1) {
      widget.value = datasource.items[index];
    }
  });
} else {
  var index = datasource.items.map(function(i){return i.Status;}).indexOf('Open');
  if(index !== -1) {
    widget.value = datasource.items[index];
  }
}
```