# Set default value for Relations table

Tags: google-app-maker

I have 2 tables, one employer and managers. I created a relations between employer (count: many) and managers (count: one). When i create a new form I can select a manager, but I did not find a way to preselect a default manager. I tried to set in the manager table and in the employer, but both did not work.

Is it possible to set a default value for a related field?

thanks!

Comment: There are several ways this could be accomplished. Here is one solution I proposed for someone else https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55881794/default-value-for-dropdown?r=SearchResults.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa Thanks it works! Could you answer this questions also: Is it possible to set a default value with is not in the list?

Comment: That would mean that you would need to create a new entry in the relation table, then reload the datasource of the relation and then essentially use the same process to find the new entry and set it as the default.